# How to distinguish oninput from typing versus clicking on the arrows of a number input?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have an `<input type='number'>`, from which I want a canvas graph to update after the user:

- clicks in the up/down arrows (which appear on desktop browser, and is achieved with `oninput`)
- types a number and hit Enter/Tab (also desktop only, achieved with `onkeydown`)
- types a number and click `->` (on mobile, achieved with `onblur`)

so, what I have so far is:

```
<input type='number' value='100' onkeydown='input(event)' onblur='input(event)' oninput='input(event)' />
```

Problem is: I don't want the graph to be updated while the user is typing a number on a desktop, but only when the typing is over (i.e. after Enter or Tab are pressed).

How can I distinguish if `oninput` came from the clicked arrows or from a numeric keyboard? I see the event property `inputType` shows `insertReplacementText` for the first and `insertText` for the second. But from their names, it doesn't appear to be the safest option.

Comment: There's currently no method available to know *how* the user changed the value (either through direct typing or through the arrows), only that the value did change. If you only want to update the UI when typing ends, either debounce the event, or use `change` instead. The latter will fire when the blur event fires *after* the user changes the value.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you! Using `change` apparently solved it.